# what could be the reason for my project is missing in .project file?

Tags: ros, eclipse, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a project from terminal and i was able to run successfully.  When try to configure eclipse for the same project, but the project is not visible in eclipse. Hence, i am not able open and run my project in eclipse.

here is the steps i followed.

cd path/to/catkin/workspace

**catkin_make --force-cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_ECLIPSE_MAKE_ARGUMENTS=-j8**

After running the above command, .project and .cproject files are created in the <catkin_workspace>/build directory.
then i tried to import my project
Click File -> Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace (Next) -> Browse (browse to catkin_workspace ->
My project is not visible here :-( ,

i noticed my project is not appearing in the .project file.  why my project is missing in .project and how can i open it in eclipse. Can anyone please help me on this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235946/what-could-be-the-reason-for-my-project-is-missing-in-.project-file?/) by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-06-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-06-02**:
I assume you're following the instructions in http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs

**Comment by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on 2016-06-03**:
Yes, i followed instructions in http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs.   But project was not visible to import from eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed this link
http://www.cnblogs.com/freedomshe/archive/2013/05/16/configure_eclipse_in_catkin.html
After following this link, problem solved.  ROS source packages can be found in build directory that was imported in eclipse.
we can not find the packages directly in eclipse existing projects while importing. we have to first import build directory, it has a source directory for all our packages.  It is important to build the project in eclipse (ctrl+b) immediately after importing to avoid semantic errors.

---

Originally posted by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) with karma: 75 on 2016-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0